# Fluid image that has initial size specified

Tags: html, css

#### Goal

I need an image that doesn't rearrange my layout when it's done loading **and** is fit inside a container.

#### Rationale

1. Rearranging part: without taking any action, I'll just see small block with a text taken from the `alt` attribute. When the image is finished loading, the text is replaced with an actual content, making the layout suddenly rearrange itself. This degrades user experience - many things are happening on screen at once, etc.
2. As for the being fit inside a container - the image can be very big. Like, `6000x3000` NASA scans big.

#### The obvious approach

I specified image's `width` and `height`. So, basically, I have `<img src="640" height="480" alt="whatever"/>` and it knows its size immediately, so the layout doesn't rearrange.

Then I added `img { max-width: 100%; }`.

But this screwed up aspect ratio of large images - it took width from container and height from `height="..."` image attribute.

So I changed that rule to `img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }`, like numerous posts here on StackOverflow and on the Internet suggest.

This works... but the first problem strikes back. My image, having now its height set to `auto` with CSS, ignores its `height="..."` attribute and is rendered initially as an unsized `alt` text again.

#### Other things I've tried

- I've tried applying restrictions to the container. Doesn't help much, the image just overflows.
- I've tried to use Javascript, by adding `height: auto` rule only after the image is loaded. This works unexpectedly bad: after the image is finished, it flashes for a brief time with wrong aspect ratio, and then suddenly it corrects itself thanks to `height: auto` (Firefox). I don't want to hide it for loading time either, because it can be animated and keeping viewers for too long from seeing the content is not acceptable.
- I've given some thought to using `background-size`, but I'll have hard time keeping the aspect ratio of its `div`.
- I'm not sure about `object-fit`. It seems to be helpful in such cases, but according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/object-fit), it's not exactly production-ready yet.

This seems like an elementary problem. Is there any simple way of achieving both goals at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by using `padding-top` trick: http://jsfiddle.net/mtfondvy/4/

The image, along with its container, fills up to 640x480 block depending on the window size, while keeping its aspect ratio. The same technique can be used to resize a div with regard to its aspect ratio.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="outer" style="width: 640px">
    <img class="inner" src="http://placekitten.com/g/640/480"/>
    <div style="padding-top: calc(100% * 480 / 640)"></div>
</div>
<p>Whatever</p>
```

Note the 480 and 640: `calc(100% * 480 / 640)` is used to compute aspect ratio of the div. Even though it's written that way, it can still be easily used with common server-side and client-side HTML templates. The advantage is that it doesn't rely on Javascript nor server-side computations.

**CSS**:

```
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.outer {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make background-size:cover; It will stretch the image as wide as possible while keeping the aspect ratio.

Height to be min-height:100%; -this will make it 100% of its parent div.

Same with width min-width:100%;

Comment: This seems to work to some extent: [http://jsfiddle.net/mtfondvy/](http://jsfiddle.net/mtfondvy/), but the resulting image is clipped. Preventing it from being clipped reduces the problem to applying `max-width` to `div` while preserving its aspect ratio.

Comment: It's almost the solution I'm looking for, but I want the object to only shrink if it's too big. The example you provided scales it up too.

Comment: Looks like [I finally got it to work](http://jsfiddle.net/mtfondvy/4/), but it relies on `calc()`.